# Fabric.js - canvas.toDatalessJSON not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

This is how i load images on to the canvas:

```
$(".img-link").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href'),
        extension = url.substr((~-url.lastIndexOf(".") >>> 0) + 2);

    if(extension !== 'svg') {
        fabric.Image.fromURL( url, function(oImg) {
            var ow = oImg.getWidth(),
                oh = oImg.getHeight();

            oImg.lockUniScaling = true;
            oImg.set({'left': ow/2, 'top': oh/2});
            canvas.add(oImg);
        });
    } else {
        var group = [];
        fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, function(objects,options) {
        var loadedObjects = new fabric.Group(group);
        loadedObjects.set({
                left: 100,
                top: 100,
                sourcePath: url
        });
        canvas.add(loadedObjects);
        canvas.renderAll();
        },function(item, object) {
                object.set('id',item.getAttribute('id'));
                group.push(object);
        });
    }
});
```

`console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON()))` gives the following output:

{"objects":[{"type":"group","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":100,"top":100,"width":200,"height":200,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"objects":[{"type":"path","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":0,"width":200,"height":200,"fill":"#aa0000","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"path":[["M",91.5,73],["c",0,-30,40,-30,40,0],["c",0,30,-40,60,-40,60],["c",0,0,-40,-30,-40,-60],["c",0,-30,40,-30,40,0]],"pathOffset":{"x":0,"y":0}}]}],"background":""}

if i check `canvas.item(0).sourcePath` it gives me `heart.svg`

Whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @Kienz Isn't the canvas.toDatalessJSON() supposed to return the `url` to the SVG instead of the SVG paths when i already set the `sourcePath: url` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `fabric.Group` instead of `fabric.Path` or `fabric.PathGroup`. Only `fabric.PathGroup` and `fabric.Path` replaces path definition with sourcePath url if you are calling `canvas.toDatalessJSON()`. 
Use that code for your svg elements:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, function(objects, options) {
   // Group elements to fabric.PathGroup (more than 1 elements) or
   // to fabric.Path
   var loadedObject = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
   // Set sourcePath
   loadedObject.set('sourcePath', url);

   canvas.add(loadedObject);
});
```

Here you can see a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/526wC/

In your jsfiddle you are using fabric.Image and not fabric.Path.

Comment: Actually, in my fiddle i am using `fabric.Image` for non SVG objects. For SVG objects i used `fabric.loadSVGFromURL` :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you set `sourcePath` attribute on `fabric.Group` object instead of `fabric.Path`.
If you set the `sourcePath` attribute to your path object it should work.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work partially for me. When i use fabric.Path then the SVG is not rendered at all but when i use `fabric.PathGroup` the SVG is rendered fine and the `canvas.DatalessJSON()` seems to work fine but now i lose the ability to `select` the SVG object so that i can move or modify it.

Comment: @LuckySoni Can you create small jsfiddle example.

Comment: strange.. it works for me in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XMwSp/ I guess its the 'other code' (which i omitted in the fiddle to keep things clean) is messing. Do have a look at the full example http://devhost.in/fab/ if you have the time. Thank you very much.